# GeoTrellis output on file

Tags: geotiff-tiff, geotrellis, hadoop-distributed-file-system

I need to process raster data stored on HDFS in GeoTIFF format using GeoTrellis. Each file is composed by 8 bands and I need to perform NDVI and other map algebra operations selecting specific bands.

I'm able to handle input files with a `MultibandGeoTiff` object:

```
val geoTiff = HadoopGeoTiffReader.readMultiband(new Path("path/to/tiff/file"))(sc)
```

and then do some processing with the function `tile.combineDouble()`. Once I have a processed tile, how can I save it on an output file (in GeoTIFF format) on HDFS or on a specific host's filesystem?